# Unable to get variable right

Tags: xml, swift

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

the problem is that the `prepareForSegue` function is not getting the `chanceRain` variable. for some reason `chanceRain` only has a value inside the task variable. Does somebody know how to fix that? I tried to fix it in playground but I can't import SWXMLHash in it.

```swift
import UIKit
import SWXMLHash

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var cellContent = [""]
    var indexOfTime = 0
    var chanceRain = ""
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.royvano.paraplu")
    var rainInt :Int = 0



    @IBOutlet var cityInput: UITextField!

    func enumerate(indexer: XMLIndexer) {
        for child in indexer.children {
            NSLog(child.element!.name)
            enumerate(child)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        var url = NSURL(string: "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?key=ca89103dfe0a8b844a0a1e1249820&q=" +
            cityInput.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-") + "/" + cityInput.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-") + "/" + "&num_of_days=2&tp=3&format=xml")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            println(url)

            var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(urlContent!)

            for elem in xml["data"]["weather"][0]["hourly"][self.indexOfTime]{

                self.chanceRain = (elem["chanceofrain"].element!.text!)

                self.defaults?.setObject(self.chanceRain, forKey: "rainPercentage")

                self.defaults?.synchronize()


                 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("btnSubmitSegue", sender: self)

            }

            println(self.chanceRain)

        })
        task.resume()

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



        if(segue.identifier == "btnSubmitSegue"){

            var svc: viewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as viewTwo

            svc.datapassed = "There is " + self.chanceRain + "% chance of rain" //dit werkt, maar chanceRain niet..?


        } }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        cellContent = ["01:00","04:00","07:00", "10:00", "13:00", "16:00", "19:00", "22:00"]
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cellContent.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default  , reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(cellContent[indexPath.row])"

        return cell }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        indexOfTime = indexPath.row



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Also the viewTwo class over here:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class viewTwo: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var datapassed:String! = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        label.text = datapassed }

}
```

Comment: Could you fix your code formatting? It's rather hard to read currently

Comment: @royvano If that's what you call correctly formatted, then I recommend you start putting some working code examples (not this one... this one doesn't work as intended) to [codereview.se]... because that was far from well formatted...

Comment: When are you triggering the segue? Is it on the same button press that triggers the function named `button(_:)`?

Comment: @ad121 the segue gets triggered when the function button is pressed

Comment: Does your `println(self.chanceRain)` statement return any value ?

Comment: @JanGregorTriebel yes it returns the right value

Comment: Could you replace `svc.datapassed = "hallo "+toString(chanceRain)` with `svc.datapassed = "hallo \(chanceRain)"` and test it ?

Comment: Since your button triggers the segue and the IBAction, chanceRain won't have a value when prepareForSegue is called. This is because you are setting chanceRain inside the block of an asynchronous function. Thus, that block takes some time to update the value of chanceRain. You can fix this by removing the segue trigger from the button and putting performSegueWithIdentifier inside the block after the for loop. That was the segue will only be triggered once the asynchronous call is resolved.

Comment: @ad121 What you're suggesting works! But I encounter another problem, made a quick video that shows the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXC4MCRs1QQ&feature=youtu.be  I set the segue via control dragging from my button to the second view controller. That segue I gave an Identifier, but when I want to remove the segue trigger from the button like you said, I can't do a performSegueWithIdentifier. Because at that moment the segue doesn't exist.. Is there another way I can do the segue without having to control drag from the button to the second view controller?

Comment: Control drag from the view controller (yellow box at top) to the second view controller.

Comment: @ad121 When I do that, it segues me to an empty view controller, which means that prepareForSegue hasn't bin executed.. It is also very weird that it shows an empty view, because I set a label and a navigation bar item, which both don't display now. they did when I connected the button with the second view controller

Comment: Did you give the segue an identifier? Did you call perform argue with identifier? Did you put a println in prepareForSegue to check that it isn't called? Are you sure that your secondviewcontroller class is linked up in the storyboard? Those are some things to double check... Specifically the println if you didn't do that already. If you already did those, would you be able to update your code?

Comment: @ad121 I really appreciate your reply's! I updated the code above. Yes, I gave the segue an identifier. Yes, I called the performSegueWithIdentifier method. When I println prepareForSegue, it returns (Function). Yes, I'm sure that I linked up de Second View Controller in the storyboard. I think the problem is something with the order of the code, but not sure how to fix that. Can you please look at the updated code above? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I mean place a println(self.chanceRain) inside your prepareForSegue if statement. If that println doesn't ever get called then you know there is an issue with the segue... If it is called then the issue is probably with how you are displaying it on the next view controller. Also I am not sure why performSegueWithIdentifier is in a for loop but based on how your code looks I am assuming that for loop only loops once?

Comment: @ad121 it is in the for loop, because otherwise I wouldn't get the value of the variable chainRain that I want. When I println (self.chainRain) in the PrepareForSegue, It just displays the right value for it, but I don't get the text on the second view controller, really weird..

Comment: It may be a problem with your second view controller. Maybe pos the code for your viewTwo class?

Comment: @ad121 
I've just edited the viewTwo class into my first post

Comment: Is your label constrained correctly so that it will show on the screen? Also put a println(data passed) in viewTwo's viewDidLoad function to see if it is correctly passed

Comment: @ad121 damn I feel stupid now haha! I forgot to constrain my label. Is there a way I can give you kudo's or something for your help?

Comment: I posted the answer to the original question in the answers below

Answer (score 0):

Since you are triggering the segue on the button press in addition to the IBAction `button(_:)`, the `chanceOfRain` variable won't be updated when the segue occurs. This is because `chanceOfRain` is updated in the block of an asynchronous call, meaning it will take time to be updated. By the time it is updated, `prepareForSegue` may already be resolved.

To fix this do not trigger the segue on the button press in the storyboard. Instead, make it a regular segue from the first ViewController to the second ViewController with an identifier. You can then call `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)` in the block of the asynchronous call after you know that `chanceOfRain` has been updated. This will ensure the data is passed correctly.